# I don't understand how Datadog is aggregating my metrics

Tags: datadog

I am trying to create a widget on my Datadog dashboard but having a hard time understanding what is going on. I have a metric that is a counter for successful queries and I want to get a time series that graphs the total count within a 1min period over time in order to visualize any significant drops in the count that would signify a problem with a server handling those queries. The query that I've tried using is something like this:

```
sum:count_metric{host}.as_count().rollup(sum, 60)
```

The `sum` at the start of the query, I believe, should be irrelevant because these metrics are only pulled from a single source. What I don't understand is as I change the display time (not sure how to word this better, but it's where I change time so the graph shows the metric over different periods of time e.g. the past 15min or past 4 hours etc. not the rollup period) the count that gets graphed changes too. The shorter the display time the lower the count. I am under the assumption that `rollup()` would aggregate the count by 1 minute so there shouldn't be any changes over different display times, but clearly that's not what's happening because when I display the past 15min the count is around 30, but if I display the past 1 day the count is around 600. What I want to see is the count hovering around 30 regardless of the display time. Another point of confusion is that when I display this timeseries using lines, the count is lower than if I were to use bars.

What am I misunderstanding about how Datadog calculates it's metrics (or just metrics in general) and how would I get the desired graph?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [enforced vs custom rollup intervals](https://docs.datadoghq.com/dashboards/functions/rollup/#rollup-interval-enforced-vs-custom). This is the key part here:

> A custom .rollup() function can be used to enforce the type of time aggregation applied (avg, min, max, count, or sum) and the time interval to rollup. However, **if a custom .rollup() function is applied and uses a smaller time interval than the Datadog limit, the Datadog limit is used instead** while still using the specified rollup method.

So you won't be able to get the granularity you are after on longer timeframes.

For your use case, take a look at [anomaly monitors](https://docs.datadoghq.com/monitors/create/types/anomaly/) and see if they will work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the values to be the same regardless of time window, then you need to normalize it as a per-second rate (instead of a count). You can then scale as needed if you still want to see average per-minute rates.

In my opinion, the 'as_count' feature is more trouble than it's worth if you are ever going to be changing the time window length. It just confuses folks.